# HLS Secure Streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-live-streaming, drm

I am implementing secure HLS streaming for my educational website like udemy and other platform , the content will be streamed from Amazon s3. I have already implemented a demo where I am streaming from my local server with encrypted HLS file while getting the chunks from server the enc.key file is also available in the network tab, So is this safe to have it or some other strategies like DRM need to apply.

Comment: Using common encryption like this, your key is available to the users and they can decrypt the video.  So, what is "safe" or not is up to your use case.  The method you're using is one of the lesser methods, but is the only way to do it short of using a DRM provider.  At the end of the day, no matter what sort of DRM scheme you use, somebody can get around it.  You have to decide what's worth it for your business use case.